# Column to Row SQL syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table:

```
--------------------------------------------
Group   Date         Value1   Value2   Value3
--------------------------------------------
A       2014-01-01   10       10       5
B       2014-01-01   12       20       25
C       2014-01-01   20       40       50
```

I want to have the following result:

```
-------------------------------------------
NewCol     A      B      C
-------------------------------------------
Value1     10     12     20
Value2     10     20     40
Value3     5      25     50
```

How can I do this in sql server 2008? Thank you.

Comment: [Searching this site alone......](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+server+convert+row+to+column) produces **697 answers** .....

Comment: row to column and column to row. that is my question actually. How to combine it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For interchanging rows and columns, you need to `UNPIVOT`(convert columns into row values) first and then `PIVOT`(rows to columns) based on `UNPIVOT` result.

```
-- Here is the result 
SELECT * FROM 
(
    -- Unpivot here using CROSS APPLY
    SELECT [Group],
    [Values],COLNAMES 
    FROM YOURTABLE
    CROSS APPLY(VALUES (Value1,'Value1'),(Value2,'Value2'),(Value3,'Value3'))
    AS COLUMNNAMES([Values],COLNAMES)
)TAB
PIVOT
(
     -- Specify the values to hold in pivoted column
     MIN([Values])
     -- Specify the name of columns
     FOR [Group] IN([A],[B],[C])
)P
ORDER BY COLNAMES
```

**WORKING OF QUERY**

You can use `CROSS APPLY` to `UNPIVOT`. `Value1` will be the columns which holds the values in column - `Value1`. `'Value1'`(in single quotes) will be the hard coded column name value(which is shown in `COLNAMES` variable. The usage of `CROSS APPLY` will generate the following result.

- **[SQL FIDDLE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/293217/cross-apply)**

[image]

Now with the data generated from `CROSS APPLY`, you are going to `PIVOT` which forms the following result.

- **[SQL FIDDLE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/293218)**

[image]

Sometimes you cannot know the values in column `Group` in advance. In such case you need to using `Dynamic Sql`. The first step in that is to get the values in the row `Group` to a variable.

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME([Group]) 
            FROM 
            (
                SELECT distinct [Group] from YOURTABLE
            ) c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
```

Now use the `PIVOT` query with `Dynamic Sql`. Why we are using `Dynamic Sql` is because `Sql Server` cannot get the column names from the variable unless and otherwise `Dynamic Sql` is used.

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = '
            SELECT * FROM 
             (
                -- Unpivot here using CROSS APPLY
                SELECT [Group],
                [Values],COLNAMES 
                FROM YOURTABLE
                CROSS APPLY(VALUES (Value1,''Value1''),(Value2,''Value2''),(Value3,''Value3''))
                AS COLUMNNAMES([Values],COLNAMES)
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 -- Specify the values to hold in pivoted column
                 MIN([Values])
                 -- Get the column names from variable
                 FOR [Group] IN('+@cols+')
            ) p            
            ORDER BY COLNAMES;'     

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

- **[SQL FIDDLE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/293220/dynamic-sql)**

Hope you understand the concepts and got your result.
Any clarifications, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PIVOT operator. See the details below:

```
select 'Value1' NewCol, A, B, C
from (select [Group], Value1 Value from YourTable) g
pivot (
  max(g.Value)
  for g.[Group] in (A, B, C)) p
union all
select 'Value2', A, B, C
from (select [Group], Value2 Value from YourTable) g
pivot (
  max(g.Value)
  for g.[Group] in (A, B, C)) p
union all  
select 'Value3', A, B, C
from (select [Group], Value3 Value from YourTable) g
pivot (
  max(g.Value)
  for g.[Group] in (A, B, C)) p
```

Or You can combine PIVOT, and UNPIVOT operators:

```
select NewCol, A, B, C
from (
  select *
  from YourTable
  unpivot (
    Value
    for NewCol in (Value1, Value2, Value3)
  ) up
) up
pivot (
  max(Value)
  for [Group] in (A, B, C)
) p
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `PIVOT` function.  That will give your answer.

Example of `PIVOT` Function

```
  SELECT <non-pivoted column>,
        [first pivoted column] AS <column name>,
        [second pivoted column] AS <column name>,
        ...
        [last pivoted column] AS <column name>
    FROM
        (<SELECT query that produces the data>)
        AS <alias for the source query>
    PIVOT
    (
        <aggregation function>(<column being aggregated>)
    FOR
    [<column that contains the values that will become column headers>]
        IN ( [first pivoted column], [second pivoted column],
        ... [last pivoted column])
    ) AS <alias for the pivot table>
    <optional ORDER BY clause>;
```

Check this Reference bro : [Click Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need `UNPIVOT`:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      G CHAR(1) ,
      V1 INT ,
      V2 INT ,
      V3 INT
    )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 'A', 10, 10, 5 ),
        ( 'B', 12, 20, 25 ),
        ( 'C', 20, 40, 50 );
WITH    cte1
          AS ( SELECT   *
               FROM     @t
               WHERE    G = 'A'
             ),
        cte2
          AS ( SELECT   *
               FROM     @t
               WHERE    G = 'B'
             ),
        cte3
          AS ( SELECT   *
               FROM     @t
               WHERE    G = 'C'
             )
    SELECT  u1.v ,
            u1.a ,
            u2.b ,
            u3.c
    FROM    ( SELECT    *
              FROM      cte1 UNPIVOT( a FOR v IN ( [V1], [V2], [V3] ) ) u
            ) u1
            JOIN ( SELECT   *
                   FROM     cte2 UNPIVOT( b FOR v IN ( [V1], [V2], [V3] ) ) u
                 ) u2 ON u1.v = u2.v
            JOIN ( SELECT   *
                   FROM     cte3 UNPIVOT( c FOR v IN ( [V1], [V2], [V3] ) ) u
                 ) u3 ON u2.v = u3.v
```

Output:

```
v   a   b   c
V1  10  12  20
V2  10  20  40
V3  5   25  50
```

Comment: Using `Cross apply` you can simply your solution